# how to get exit status from command in expect script

Tags: linux, ksh, expect

Below is an shell script I have written to automate entering the password for the `vpnc` command. The expect works fine and vpnc activated automatically after password entered, but I need to get the exit status of the `vpnc` command. How can I get the exit status of `vpnc`?

```
VPNC=/bin/vpnc

expect_ACTIVATE=`cat << EOF
set timeout -1
spawn  $VPNC 
expect    :            {send Pass123\r}
expect eof
EOF`

expect -c  "$expect_ACTIVATE"
```

I've tried doing the following to get the exit status into `STATUS`, but it's not quite right:

```
expect_ACTIVATE=`cat << EOF
set timeout -1
spawn  $VPNC 
expect    :            {send Pass123\r}
STATUS=` echo $? `
expect eof
EOF`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing this. I didn't try it myself. Let's see if it works.

```
expect_ACTIVATE=`cat << EOF`
set timeout -1
spawn  $VPNC 
expect    :            {send Pass123\r}
expect "\\$ "
send "status=`echo $?\r`"
expect eof
EOF
```